# stream_socket_client via http proxy

Tags: php, sockets, ssl

I'm working on APNS (Apple Push Notification Service).
I'm doing it as tutorials said:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

But on my server, I have to connect to the internet via a HTTP proxy, so I always got timeout error with those code. How can I set http proxy for strem_socket_client with ssl protocol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best way is to set [`proxy`](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.proxy) options with `stream_context_create`:

```php
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
            )
        )
       );
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php for full http options.
Maybe you will have to set [`request_fulluri`](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.request-fulluri) to true.

Comment: I just wanna point out that proxy is not a supported param by stream_socket_client() and is completely ignored. http://php.net/manual/en/context.socket.php